# NodeJS application cannot get input from Python shell

Tags: python, node.js, linux, shell

I have a NodeJS application running in Raspberry Pi. Application uses Pythonshell library [Python Shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) for communicating between NodeJS application and python script using stdin as interprocess communication method.

When I start the application normally from shell (node app.js) communication between NodeJS app and python app (meas.py) works fine. However, I would like to start my NodeJS app when Raspberry Pi boots. I have started the app in crontab using command:

```
@reboot /home/pi/ble/startup.sh
```

Application starts nicely and it also starts the meas.py. However, it never receives messages from meas.py and shell.on('message') is never called.  Any suggestions?

```
var shell = new PythonShell('meas.py');
shell.on('message', function (message) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I managed to found a solution. I used init.d script to start application on startup.

More information can be found from [Node startup](https://github.com/chovy/node-startup)